# Radio buttons on worksheet stay selected for Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel, activex, excel-2016

I can replicate this "feature" only on one specific Workbook (with plenty of nice code in it), which was used for about 2 years, built in Excel 2010 (32 bits), working there quite ok and currently trying it in Excel 2016 (32 bits).

The "feature" is the following - the Active-X radio buttons  in Excel 2016 seem to function with a 30 second lag. After about 30 seconds, the one(s) that should not be selected become unselected. The radio buttons do not have any event associated to them.

Like this:

[image]

Tried:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
Application.EnableAnimations=True 
Application.EnableEvents = True 
Application.CalculateFullRebuild 
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
'+ Deleting the radio buttons and creating them again.
'+ Both *.xlsb & *.xlsm
```

---

The references:

[image]

---

Sometimes this "stops" for about a minute or so and the selection works ok, but then continues.

Comment: Do they have the same GroupName? After enabling Design mode -> `Right click -> Properties -> GroupName`. It might somehow be corrupted when you go from Excel 2010 to 2016..

Comment: Could possibly be multiple copies of the controls on top of each other, too.

Comment: @Tehscript - group name is the same. That is why after 30 seconds only 1 stays selected.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - nope,  no buttons over each other.